# What does "they were taken for being taken in" mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I have difficulty interpreting this line:

> they were taken for being taken in

It is from [*Some*](http://www.nukeresister.org/some-by-daniel-berrigan/) by the late Daniel Berrigan. Exerpt:

> Some stood and stood and stood.
>   They were taken for fools,
>   they were taken for being taken in.

Can someone rephrase it in simple English please?

Comment: Would you please provide a link to the *whole* poem, so that we can read the 3 quoted lines in context, with at least some change of being able to understand them?

Comment: sure: http://www.democracynow.org/2016/5/2/the_cause_is_the_heart_s

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the link into your question and also corrected some other matters.  But, sorry, I still don't understand the poem!

Comment: TrevorD, if you know about the poem's life as a peace and justice activist, I'm sure you'll understand better this sweat poet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Taken for..." means to be mistaken or recognized for something.  To be "taken for a fool" means to have been seen to be a fool.

"To be taken in" means to be fooled or deceived.

"To be taken for taken in" would therefore mean to be seen to have been fooled.

Comment: That's it, I believe as well. In the context of the poem, because "they stood and stood" (didn't abandon the 'cause'), they were taken for fools (or being fooled).

Comment: @medica, my understaning is that those who `stood and stood`, are those who are deceived and stagnated, in contrast to who they walked after the cause. Do you agree Cyberherbalist?

Comment: @Jand - Please note that they were *taken for (/as) taken in*, not simply "taken in", which would mean "deceived". The later lines, *"Why do you stand?” they were asked, and “Why do you walk?"* and their response: *"Because of the children..."* indicates (to me) that both the continued standing and walking were both acts of conscience. If you do not understand the double "taken", I think you're missing the meaning of the line (and the answer above.)

Comment: medica, you are right. the poet considers both as acts of conscience {resistance/disobedience}.. By the way what `risen bread` mean hear?